# php string explode on (-) characters

Tags: php

I have a string something like this:

`$string = "small (150 - 160)"`

Is there a way I could store 150 in the variable `$min` and 160 in the variable `$max` in php?

Comment: Is it just this one string format you need to work with? Do you have other examples? Is the spacing always consistent?

Comment: *something like this* wouldn't result into a suitable answer. You should be more specific e.g. if input string could contain more digits any where else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function minMax($string) {
  $digits = explode("-", $string);
  return filter_var_array($digits, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

// $yourString = "small (150 - 160)"
$values = minMax( $yourString );
$min = $values[0]; $max = $values[1];
```

The function uses `explode` to remove "-" and create an array. The string to left of "-" is placed in $digits[0] and to right in $digits[1].

PHP filters are then used to remove non integer characters from the array strings. Note I assume you are working with whole numbers. `filter_var_array` won't work with decimal points but you can use `filter_var` instead with the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` flag to retain decimals points.

```
function minMax($string) {
  return filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION );
}

$values = minMax( "small (150 - 160.4)" );
$number = explode("-", $values);
$min = $number[0]; $max = $number[1];
```

In the decimal example immediately above any "." will be retained. If strings can contain non numeric periods then you will need to remove leadin "."s from your output e.g. if string = *"big... (150 - 160.4)"* then $min will contain '...150' to prevent leading periods `$min = trim($min,'.');`.

Answer (score 0):

This `PHP` script will solve your problem:

```
$string = "small (150 - 160)";
$tmp = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", " ", $string);
$tmp = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $tmp));
$tmp = explode(' ', $tmp);

$min = $tmp[0];
$max = $tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "small (150 - 160)";
$string = preg_replace('/[^\d-]/', '', $string); // replace everything not a digit and not a "-" with empty string ('')
list( $min, $max ) = explode('-', $string); // split by "-" and store in $min and $max

var_dump( $min);
var_dump( $max );
```

**Output**

```
string(3) "150"
string(3) "160"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a predictably formatted string with no optional characters can be a good task for `sscanf()`. Better than `preg_` functions, if the format parameter contains `%d` or `%f`, then the isoated nueric substring will be cast as an integer or float (respectively).  The `*` symbol is a capture suppressor -- meaning the matched substring will not be assigned to a variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ubYcd))

```
$string = "small (150 - 160)";

sscanf($string, '%*[a-z] (%d - %d)', $min, $max);

var_export([$min, $max]);
```

Output (int-type values):

```
array (
  0 => 150,
  1 => 160,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation generally improves any code only answer. In this case it would be useful to explain what you are doing and also why you chose to use `!` instead of `/`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579620/regular-expression-with-exclamation-marks-on-both-sides-d